# Is there a reliable way to compare two .jar files?

Tags: jar, diff

I am trying to improve our development process. As part of that, when a developer needs to redeploy some services as part of testing their changes, I wish to improve our process by only redeploying those services that have *actually* changed - that is, the fat jar that is running has any source changes.

Since we do not at the moment have a sophisticated versioning scheme, that is unfortunately not an option.

My initial idea was as follows:

1. Save a list of jars (or hashes thereof) for the previous deployment, which is currently running.
2. Upon redeploying, first assemble all relevant jars. Perform an md5sum over the resulting jar files and compare with current. If it matches, add it to a list of exclusions that will not be redeployed.
3. If the hashes do not match, redeploy.

Unfortunately, after quite some searching and trying to get this working, I have found out that even two jars with *completely identical source and resource content* will yield differing checksums: this is due to the fact that a jar is simply a glorified zip and as such, does have file headers indicating dates. Unfortunately this means that a simple `md5sum first.jar second.jar` will never work.

Are there any standard approaches to this? If possible, I would like to avoid extracting the contents to some temporary directory and comparing those as with the number of possible services to redeploy, I would likely not have saved much time in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that we solved this issue was to let our build tool manage the comparison instead of trying to do it ourselves. We saved the previous build information on our build server and simply rebuilt the projects - in this case Gradle notices which jars are up to date and which are not.

After that we simply compared the checksums of the "previous" build and the "current" build, which now correctly states which jars were truly updated.

EDIT:

As of 28.05.2019, it is rather easy to get reproducible builds of Spring Boot Jars without relying on saved build information. See [this](https://gist.github.com/pgilad/52d6d425d83a9c44a2a23149a1272349) gist as well as the therein linked Spring [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14494).